# Android state_selected doesn't work

Tags: android

i have a problem with state_selected in selector.

```
<item
    android:state_selected="true"

    android:drawable="@drawable/red"
    ></item>

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"

    android:drawable="@drawable/blue"
    ></item>

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/white"></item>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text = "Hello"
        android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The state_pressed works fine (the setEnabled method has a "true" value).
Any suggestions ?

Comment: on which view do you apply this selector?

Comment: please provide the full code of your layout

Comment: I added the layout code.

Comment: Anyone can help me ???

Answer (score 2):

To have a `@drawable/red` background from your selector (`android:state_selected="true"`) you should select your `TextView`:

```
findViewById(R.id.list_item).setSelected(true);
```

For better understanding of each view's state please check
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#attr_android:state_selected